# D3.js line graph not touching the endpoint

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Below is the code which draws a line graph:

```
var xLabels = d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2016, 0, 1), new Date(2016, 5, 31)]).range([0, w]);    
var incidentData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 350, 208];
                //console.log(xLabels);
                var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, incidentData.length]).range([0, w]);
                var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(incidentData)]).range([h, 0]);

                var line = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function (d, i) {
                        return x(i);
                    })
                    .y(function (d) {
                        return y(d);
                    })

                var graph = d3.select("#incident").append("svg:svg")
                      .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
                      .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
                    .append("svg:g")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(" + 70 + "," + m[0] + ")");

                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xLabels).ticks(d3.time.months).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%B")).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(true);
                graph.append("svg:g")
                      .attr("class", "x axis")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
                      .call(xAxis);

                var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");
                graph.append("svg:g")
                      .attr("class", "y axis")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
                      .call(yAxisLeft);

                graph.append("svg:path")
                    .attr("d", line(incidentData))
                    .attr('class', 'line');

                graph.selectAll("dot")
                    .data(incidentData)
                    .enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("r", 2.5)
                    .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(i); })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d); });

                graph
                    .attr("stroke-dasharray", 500 + " " + 500)
                    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 500)
                  .transition() // Call Transition Method
                    .duration(4000) // Set Duration timing (ms)
                    .ease("linear") // Set Easing option
                    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

But the last line does not touch the point 208. 
Here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/AbhilashDK/ksto1reb/7/
Please somebody can you explain what is wrong with it.

Thanks and Regards,
Abhilash D K

Comment: You can slightly adjust the stroke: https://jsfiddle.net/bopstzcf/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado post it as answer

Comment: Thanks, but I'm too lazy today for that! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

[Gerardo Furtado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5768908/gerardo-furtado) Thanks for the reply. It worked.

Hi guys follow [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bopstzcf/) this addresses the problem.
The solution was to increase the graph attrs from

```
graph
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", 500 + " " + 500)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 500)
```

to

```
graph
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", 550 + " " + 550)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 550)
```

Regards,
Abhilash D K

Comment: Now the explanation: when I put my eyes on "500" I saw it as a magic number. I have little respect for magic numbers, so I immediately tweaked it a little bit, and my first guess (550) worked. I was on my mobile then, but now that I'm on my laptop I can retrieve the correct length of your line: it is 529.6993408203125. So, you can use 530 instead of 550.

Comment: PS: Accept your own answer (SO allows it).